# CGAL rounding points so that they remain coplanar

Tags: c++, geometry, precision, computational-geometry, cgal

I have a set of `Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel::Point_3` points that are coplanar.  I would like to be able to serialize the points to a database in double precision and then be able to read the points back into an exact precision space and have them be coplanar.  Specifically, my workflow is CGAL -> Postgres using Postgis -> SFCGAL.  SFCGAL requires that the points be coplanar and uses exact constructions.

I know how to write the geometry, but I'm not sure how to go about rounding the points so that they remain coplanar.  Obviously the points read will have a loss of precision and will be slightly transformed compared to the originals, but I only need them to be within roughly a e-04 distance from their respective points.

Unfortunately, projecting the points onto a plane after reading them is a last resort option.  It doesn't work very well for my purposes.

Comment: Are you able to store more than just points? For example can you store the fact that point are supposed to be coplanar? If you only store double precision points without extra information, I'm afraid you're stuck. You can see the double numbers as a nodes on a 3D irregular grid. Given an arbitrary plane, in general you won't be able to find 4 points on the grid lying on the plane and close to your input points.

Comment: I can store more information than the points, but the points still need to be valid.  I have tried creating my geometry using sfcgal in c++, checking it is valid, then writing the geometry to the database using sfcgal's writer, but the points still don't count as coplanar.  My intuition was that this rounding geometric approach might not be possible (for the same reason you gave), but I hoped maybe my intuition was wrong or that given the density of the grid relative to the e-04 distance, it might work out.  It doesn't need to be the same plane, just a plane close enough to the points.

Comment: IIRC SFCGAL uses an exact number type so the pb is as you mentioned how you import the points in SFCGAL. What I had in mind when I asked whether you can keep some extra information was to also store some coplanarity info and project the points onto a plane once imported. However this means that you have a particular pipeline and won't work in general.